# How the Google Play Books page zoom-in and zoom-out is implemented?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, google-play-books

I am newbie to Android development, need one help. How the Google Play Books onclick page zoom-out and zoon-in animation implemented? Are they using RecyclerView?
[Google Play Books page zoom out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6kkA.gif)

Comment: Your link doesn't show any animation (and don't ask me to install anything).

Comment: Hi @kalabalik, I have edited the image. It is now showing the animation.